# Limit as x approaches 0 from the left: $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \sin^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{2+e^\frac{1}{x}}}\right)$

Tags: limits, functions, trigonometry

Help me find the limit as x approaches 0 from the left:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \sin^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{2+e^\frac{1}{x}}}\right)$$

Thanks,

Comment: Look at each part of the function in turn: $\tfrac1x$; then $2+\mathbb e^\tfrac1x$; then $\frac{1}{2+\mathbb e^\tfrac1x}$; and finally $\arcsin (\frac{1}{2+\mathbb e^\tfrac1x})$

Comment: Can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Following [user164587](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/164587)'s comment:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1x&=-\infty\\
\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{1/x}&=0\\
\lim_{x\to0^-}2+e^{1/x}&=2\\
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1{2+e^{1/x}}&=\frac12\\
\lim_{x\to0^-}\arcsin\left(\frac1{2+e^{1/x}}\right)&=\arcsin\frac12\\
&=\frac\pi6
\end{align}

Thus, we have $\lim_{x\to0^-}\arcsin\left(\frac1{2+e^{1/x}}\right)=\frac\pi6$.

[Helpful graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYyVs.png)

Comment: Why is $e^{-\infty}=0$? Think of the graph of $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x->0^{-}} \sin^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{2+e^\frac{1}{x}}}\right)=\sin^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{2+\lim_{x->0^{-}} e^\frac{1}{x}}}\right)$$ and note that $\lim_{x->0^{-}} e^\frac{1}{x}=0$

Comment: How do you assume limx−>0−e1x=0

Comment: @user3924310: When $x\rightarrow0^-$, $\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow-\infty$.